# Why do I get a nonassign error in the angular-bootstrap tabset?

Tags: angularjs, twitter-bootstrap, angular-ui, angular-ui-bootstrap-tab

```
  <tabset class="paygrade-tabs">
    <tab ng-repeat="tab in rps.currentPayGrade | orderBy: 'payGrade.code' : true track by $index" ng-click="changeTab(tab)" active="activeTabId === tab.id">
      <tab-heading>
        <span>{{tab.payGrade.code}}</span>
      </tab-heading>
    </tab>
  </tabset>
```

This gives me an error for some reason:

```
Error: [$compile:nonassign] http://errors.angularjs.org/1.4.14/$compile/nonassign?p0=activeTabId%20%3D%3D%3D%20tab.id&p1=active&p2=tab
    at angular.js:38
    at q (angular.js:9157)
    at m (angular.js:9170)
    at angular.js:14777
    at n.$digest (angular.js:16219)
    at n.$apply (angular.js:16492)
    at g (angular.js:10872)
    at A (angular.js:11070)
    at XMLHttpRequest.w.onload (angular.js:11011)
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: can u create a working plunkr

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's because you pass an expression to `active`:

```
active="activeTabId === tab.id"
```

It needs something that it can bind to and write back to.

Pass a variable instead:

```
active="myVariable"
```

Where `myVariable` is the index of the active tab.